# How to read rocket::Data to a string inside a fairing?

Tags: stream, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement a fairing in Rocket that logs the bodies of requests coming in. Unfortunately, since the fairing `on_request` method only gets a reference to the `rocket::Data` in the request, I can't call `data.open()`.

Here's the fairing I have so far:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Logger {
}

impl Fairing for Logger {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Request / response logger",
            kind: Kind::Request | Kind::Response
        }
    }

    fn on_request(&self, request: &mut Request, data: &Data) {
        if request.method() == Method::Post {
            println!("Request came in!");
            let mut dataStr = "".to_string();
            data.open().read_to_string(&mut dataStr);
            println!("{:?}", dataStr);
        }
    }

    fn on_response(&self, request: &Request, response: &mut Response) {
    }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, I get this error:

```
379 |        data.open().read_to_string(&mut dataStr);
    |        ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Is there any way to log the data without consuming it? If not, is there another way to implement a logging fairing like this?

Comment: [`fn open(self)`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/struct.Data.html#method.open) *The method consumes the `Data` instance.*  You could maybe use `peek` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to log the data without consuming it?

No. Check out the documentation for [`Data::open`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/struct.Data.html#method.open):

> Returns the raw data stream.
>
> The stream contains all of the data in the body of the request, including that in the peek buffer. The method consumes the `Data` instance. This ensures that a `Data` type always represents all of the data in a request.

HTTP request bodies are *streams* of data. These streams are read-once. If you were to log the body of the request, the data would then be gone and your actual handler would have nothing to work with.

> is there another way to implement a logging fairing like this?

I don't know of any, but it seems like a brittle idea to start with. If someone were to POST a 1GB file, do you really want that entire thing logged?

The closest alternative I can think of is to take the owned `Data` in the handler, open it up, then "tee" the output of it to both your real code and save it somewhere, log-wise.

See also:

- [How do I read an Iron Request in both middleware and the handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36435372/155423)